# Why did no New Testament books mention AD70?

Tags: history, prophecy, new-testament, temple, messiah

My full question is; which of the New Testament books were written **after AD70?**  Assuming there are several, why did none of them mention the 'earth-shattering' events of AD70?  The destruction of the temple by Rome fulfilled one of Jesus' own prophecies (Matt. 24:1-3) and its theological significance was central to Christianity. (John 2:19-22)  It would have at least been alluded to, surely.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic, since this question does not reference any specific biblical text and therefore no hermeneutical methods can be applied. It's an interesting question though - some would of course argue that Jesus own prophecies such as Mt 24:1-3 were written in after-the-fact of the temple's destruction.

Comment: I share Steve Taylor's disquiet about this Q's lack of fit with the "on-topic" guidelines for Hermeneutics.SE. I've had a quick look at the [History.SE] guidelines, though, and I think it would fit there. Sometimes "*why NOT x...*" questions **can** be interesting, answerable, and illuminating.

Comment: Another option would be re-write the question to ask whether John 2:19ff is, in fact, a reference to the destruction of the temple -- noting, in passing, that the NT has no *direct* reference to the its destruction in 70 CE.

Comment: Im not sure how to rephrase it.  Perhaps you are right as this stack has a hermeneutic emphasis.  Ill try Christianity stack.

Comment: Many scholars say that Mark chapter 13 contains authorial references to the events of 70 CE.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/in-acts-743-why-did-the-author-write-babylon-rather-than-damascus/23187#23187), which suggests Acts 7.43 alludes to AD 70.